# Geany compiling

Tags: c, geany

Don't know where to put this...
But I'm running Geany on 2 systems (laptop and desktop).  On my laptop it works perfectly, but on my desktop when I run the code i get this error:

'"./whatevername"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

I can't figure out wtf is wrong with it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If I may give a small help: you need to set the PATH variable. On Windows machines, it's in the registry. Here's how you do it:
http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx

Otherwise, whatever your compiler migth be (gcc, tcc, cpp) will not be found.