# Use of terminal and compiler in geany for windows7

Tags: c++

How  can we integrate a terminal and compiler to geany message window in windows7 so that i can excute the c++ program ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll be very quick on this one because that's a question that gets asked a lot here.

First, you need to install the compiler (gcc and g++), then, you need to edit the %PATH% environment variable of Windows 7. Just add the directory where the gcc.exe and g++.exe are located. And, voilà.

Here's yet another related question: [Geany compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588806/geany-compiling)

For your terminal question, I don't know if the VTE plugin is available for windows. You should definitely use that instead of the windows cmd... 
Usually, executing a program is done by pressing F5.